# Using std::vector as data buffer

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to use std::vector as a memmory buffer:

```
int main( )
{
    int i = 0x01020304;
    size_t size = sizeof(int);
    std::vector<char> data;

    data.insert( data.end(), (char*)&i,  (char*)(&i  + size) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << int(data[i]) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting output 
4
3
2
1

But I got

```
4
3
2
1
51
73
-107
81
-9
127
0
0
36
-7
84
-50
```

Can some one explaing what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `(char*)(&i  + size)` you increase a pointer to `int` instead of a pointer to char. Since `size` seems to be `4` in your case you find yourself adding the data of `4` ints instead of `4` chars.

```
auto cp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
data.insert( data.end(), cp,  cp  + size );
```

Comment: I got an error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'char *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
But works fine with reinterpret cast

Answer (score 2):

size is in bytes, so you need to increase the char*, not int*.

```
data.insert( data.end(), (char*)&i,  (char*)(&i)+size );
```

Comment: @Jeka Then please award the answer, so that it's crystal clear for others reading this question in future.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to other questions, when you avoid code duplicate and make it more readable you also avoid some mistakes:

```
int i = 0x01020304;
std::vector<char> data;
char *begin = reinterpret_cast<char *>( &i );

data.insert( data.end(), begin,  begin + sizeof(i) ) );
```

you probably would need to work with different types:

```
template<typename T>
void insertData( std::vector<char> &data, T value )
{
    char *begin = reinterpret_cast<char *>( &value );
    data.insert( data.end(), begin,  begin + sizeof(value) ) );
}
```